# SSIS Advanced Editor for Data Conversion

Tags: ssis, data-conversion, truncation

In SSIS I have a truncation error under Data Conversion Input. Howerver in the  "Advanced Editor for Data Conversion" the property "TruncationRowDisposition" is grayed out. Ive always been unsure why the property is listed when its always grayed out. It makes me think there is a way or circumstance where it would not be grayed out. I need to set this property to RD_IgnoreFailure if possible. I could not find a link on here that answered this question but Im sure there is and I just missed it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the error:

> AIM_Outbound:Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput
> method on component "Data Conversion - Get Gender,
> Cell_Phone" (23) failed with error code 0xC020902A while
> processing input "Data Conversion Input" (24). The
> identified component returned an error from the
> ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the
> component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data
> Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages

> AIM_Outbound:Error: The "Data Conversion - Get
> Gender, Cell_Phone.Outputs[Data Conversion
> Output].Columns[Cell_Phone]" failed because truncation
> occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Data
> Conversion - Get Gender, Cell_Phone.Outputs[Data
> Conversion Output].Columns[Cell_Phone]" specifies failure
> on truncation. A truncation error

> AIM_Outbound_Students:Error: Data conversion failed
> while converting column "Cell_Phone_ORI" (259) to column
> "Cell_Phone" (32). The conversion returned status value 4
> and status text "Text was truncated or one or more
> characters had no match in the target code page.".

Boss has seen this issue in the past and tried to troubleshoot it to no avail. It keeps happening so he has asked me to explore ignore truncation. The error has not happened in the last 3 months but he and other developers have been unable to find the "bad data" in the past.

Comment: One tip could be just save the data into a stage table with all NVARCHAR(MAX).  Then use an SP to do some data validation first then save to the table you want to insert into.  So you can say select col where MAX(LEN(COL)) > 50 for example, and then move those to new table or mark as not processed.  Then load the rest.  Then you have the ones getting truncated in a table or flagged and can go back and fix later (even send an alert if it has that criteria)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the truncation row disposition to *Ignore Failure* on the Data Conversion output, not the input.

You can do this from both the Advanced Editor or by clicking the Configure Error Output button on the Default Editor (see screenshot below)

[image: SSIS data conversion task editor]